# Populating gmaps infowindows with data from .json file

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

i currently have a maps project which generates markers and clusters from latitude and longitude data stored in a json file. I am trying to populate the contents of the infowindow with other data, also stored in the json file. Is there a simple way of adjusting my existing code to accommodate this?

The current code:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="data.json"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="markerclusterer.js"></script>

<script>
    function initialize() {
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(34.777491, 64.5852620);

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 3,
            center: center,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var markers = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            var dataPhoto = data.photos[i];
            var infoWin = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataPhoto.latitude,
                dataPhoto.longitude);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                icon: "images/gps.svg"
            });
            (function(m, infoWindow, idx) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(m, 'click', function(evt) {
                    infoWindow.setContent('<p style="color:#008ae6;"><b>Header</b></p><p><b>ID:</b> photo_id</p>' +
                        '<p><b>Owner: </b> owner_id</p>' +
                        '<p><b>Upload Date:</b> upload_date</p>' +
                        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i>Button 1</button> ' + idx);
                    infoWindow.open(map, m);

                })
            })(marker, infoWin, i);
            markers.push(marker);
        }
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
            imagePath: 'images/m'
        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<script>
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-12846745-20']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script');
        ga.type = 'text/javascript';
        ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' === document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>

  <body>
    <div id="map-container"><div id="map"></div></div>
  </body>
```

Example of one of the many json fields:

```
{"photo_id": 57819, "photo_title": "Burg Hohenwerfen", "photo_url": "http://www.panoramio.com/photo/57819", "photo_file_url": "http://mw2.google.com/mw-panoramio/photos/medium/57819.jpg", "longitude": 13.189259, "latitude": 47.483221, "width": 500, "height": 333, "upload_date": "05 October 2006", "owner_id": 8060, "owner_name": "Norbert MAIER", "owner_url": "http://www.panoramio.com/user/8060"}
```

In the current code I have included fields from the json file where I would like to include the data. Example: `'<p><b>Owner: </b> owner_id</p>' +`

Of course, if I were to just enter some text in these fields it would display the same infowindow for every marker shown on the map. I would like these to be unique to the marker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have idx, which is the index on the item in the json data.

```
(function(m, infoWindow, idx) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(m, 'click', function(evt) {
    var content = '<h3>' + data.photos[idx].photo_title + '</h3> <img src="' + data.photos[idx].photo_url + '">';  
    // etcetera. format like you need it 
    infoWindow.setContent(content);
    infoWindow.open(map, m);
  })
}) (marker, infoWin, i)  ;; the i of the for-loop becomes idx in the on-marker-click event
```

I haven't tested it.  Let me know if it works